# Avoid changing value in client using developer tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, browser, developer-tools

We are using HTML5, Foundation by ZURB and AngularJS for our application.

We want to deny the user access to the values of the Angular objects (I mean scope variables) using developer tool console.

Kindly someone help me in this, how do we keep users from changing the values in console?

Comment: I don't think you can prevent DevTools functionality.

Comment: That's not possible. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Nitek: I have some sensitive data in the scope variables, based on that we are deriving the logic in back end.

Comment: @KarthiSanjivi you should get acquainted with the general idea of client-server apps. Data from client should always remain distrusted. That is where from arise double checks, for example - which should be performed both on client and server. If you have a trouble like you describe you should change the way server and client communicate

Comment: Thanks @Kirill Slatin. I try to do same and comeback if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is executed in the browser, on the client's machine.
Developer tools are explicitely meant for the task you want to prevent.
That said: even if it was possible to deny access to the scope variables, it should be prohibited by future versions of the browser or dev tool, since it is likely to pose a security risk, apart from being a generally bad idea.